# Why I am getting errors even the web address I am typing is correct?

Tags: windows, browser

Even I am typing the web address correctly, still It is showing 404 error. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DNS cache stores the locations (IP addresses) of webservers that contain pages which you have recently viewed. If the location of the web server changes before the entry in your DNS cache updates, you will be unable to access the site.
If you encounter a large number of HTML 404 error codes, you may need to clear your DNS cache. Once you clear your DNS cache, your computer will query nameservers for the new DNS information.

---

Clear DNS cache:

- Open Command Prompt
- Type `ipconfig /flushdns` and press Enter.